# static Java field not initialized when a static method is called

Tags: java

I have a class defined like this:

```
class MyClass {
    private static final String name = "<some string>";
    private static final String schema = "{<some json here>}";
    public static final MySchemaObject schemaObj = MyUtils.staticSchema(name, schema);   // Line1

    public static MySchemaObject getStaticSchema() {
        return schemaObj;
    }
}
```

Another class calls this class in a static initializer:

```
class AnotherClass {
    private static final MySchemaObject schemaObject = MyClass.getStaticSchema();   <===== Always null
    ........
}
```

In the class `AnotherClass`, the static variable `schemaObject` is always initialzied into null. This indicates that the `Line1` in MyClass is not called by the time the method `getStaticSchema` is called.

My understanding is that static variable are created before any static method can be called, but it seems not the case.

Can someone please help me understand this?

EDIT: MyUtils.staticSchema will never retur null;

Comment: *"This indicates that the Line1 in `MyClass` is not called by the time the method `getStaticSchema` is called."* or that it is `MyUtils.staticSchema` that simply returns null.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Do you have a circular initialization setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possible reasons:

1. `MyUtils.staticSchema` returns `null` or
2. `AnotherClass` is initialized during the initialization of `MyClass` due to a cyclic dependency.

I assume that you've already verified/ruled out option #1 so I'll focus on the second one:

Non-trivial static field initialization that depends on other classes can be problematic, because it can introduce long dependency chains and even dependency loops in class initialization.

If class `A` calls a method of class `B` during class initialization and class `B` calls a method of class `A` during class initialization, then there's a loop: that means that *some code* will see half-initialized classes.

If your `MyClass` somehow (directly or indirectly) touches `AnotherClass` during class initialization then it's quite possible tha the call to `MyClass.getStaticSchema()` is actually executed *before* `schemaObj` is initialized.

The best solution is to make the class initialization of any class depend on as few classes as possible.

Simple sample demonstrating the problem:

```
class A {
    public static final String CONSTANT_IN_A = B.CONSTANT_IN_B;
    public static final String ANOTHER_VALUE = "Value " + (Math.random() * 0 + 1);
}

class B {
    public static final String CONSTANT_IN_B = "B version of " + A.ANOTHER_VALUE;
}
```

If you try to print `A.CONSTANT_IN_A` the output will be `B version of null`, because during the initialization of `B.CONSTANT_IN_B` the field `ANOTHER_VALUE` in `A` will not yet have been initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check if a circular dependency caused this. It is quite possible because I am sure MyUtils.staticSchema will never return null.

Comment: Putting breakpoints in `MyClass.getStaticSchema()` and `MyUtils.staticSchema(name, schema)` would show you the order in which they are executed. Note that debugging this might result in weird behaviour, as debugging during class initialization can easily influence the class initalization order and thus hide/change/destroy the behaviour/bug. `System.out.println` might be a simple tool, but it's your friend in these kinds of cases.